# Gradle Android Studio Integration

Tags: android, gradle

Does anyone has any good step by step tutorial for integrating gradle with android studio. I am following this official google docs for setting up gradle:

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Simple-build-files and so far gradle keeps complaining at each step. I am not even sure about how the build.gradle file should look like for a simple hello world application.
This is my current build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.6'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
}
android {
    buildToolsVersion "17.0"
    compileSdkVersion 17
}
```

Gradle is throwing the following error:

```
 Error Code:
    1
  Output:
    /Users/xxx/Downloads/MyApplication/App/build/res/all/debug/values/values.xml:12: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
```

I am a newbie with respect to gradle.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

About your error message:
*No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.*

You are using the ActionBarCompat style. So you have to add this dependency to your script.
Add:

```
dependencies {

    // Support Libraries
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.0'
}
```

In order to use it you have to download the last support-appcompat.
Open your SDK Manager and install/update the Android Support Repository, Android Support Library v19.

Also I suggest you to update your script with the last versions.
Use Android Studio 0.4.0.

```
buildscript {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'
        }
    }
    apply plugin: 'android'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 19
        buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

        defaultConfig {
          minSdkVersion XX //Insert here your level
          targetSdkVersion 19
       }
    }

    dependencies {

        // Support Libraries
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.0'
    }
```

Comment: I have the android support repo updated. As far as the error i wasn't trying to use the actionBar at all. I was just trying to build a default java file and it showed that errror

Comment: I had a similar problem when using `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'` The problem ended up being that the latest version of the support library was missing certain assets. So using `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18+'` worked.

Answer (score 0):

you did not add compile `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3` or your compatible version.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: add this dependencies com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3 or your compatible version. it will provide themes you use.